# Getting Response Pending from paypal

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate paypal account to my portal it was working well but now its showing me paypal response Pending. Please help me if i am doing something wrong or forgot. and tell me why its showing pending when every thing looks fine.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to go into your transaction details in your seller account, and see why the transaction is pending.  If you are using IPN, you should also be seeing it displayed as pending for the transaction status, but you should also be getting a pending reason back that will tell you why it is pending.  I can take a look at it on my side if you would like but I would need a transaction id.